# Make backspace delete character and enter insert mode when in normal mode

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I want the backspace to behave the same in normal mode as insert mode and it should also enter insert mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `:nnoremap <bs> Xi`
together with `:set bs=2`

Comment: Not a big deal but I think `:set bs=2` might be considered "the old way" and `:set bs=indent,eol,start` the more conventional way to do the same thing.

Comment: more info regarding backspace and delete, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems